# wrapping state variables in struct

Tags: solidity, struct, openzeppelin-contracts, state-variable

I asked this [question](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/why-are-state-variables-wrapped-in-a-struct/12291) in OZ forum and I'm asking it here again. The question is Why a state variable is wrapped in a struct in their `Counters` library. Please see the question in that post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Struct helps you to reduce the stack height while compiling. For compilations that have many threads, or say many local variables, (where stack support only 16) you may run into this error:-

> Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly: Variable headStart is 1 slot(s) too deep inside the stack

But struct helps to reduce the number of local variables and consider them together as a single variable. And thus avoiding the error.

This [article](https://soliditydeveloper.com/stacktoodeep) may help more about this.

Comment: Also, you may need keywords 'memory' or 'calldata' along with struct if you are using many variables into a struct. 
Eg;-  
struct memory myStruct {var1;var2;]

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Yes, this is a benefit of using a struct. Put it in a specific context, why is the Counters library using it then? There is only one state variable in the struct, so it is not helping reduce # of local variables. I thought it was used to anti-reading from storage directly, but it appeared not to be the case, after a few experiments.